# Postgres queries for JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, jsonb

I have a table called cust_data which stores id and JSON object. I want to write postgres select statements to fetch:

1. select all id's where "gender": "Female" is not present in persons array [this should return id#3 from below data]
2. select all id's where "gender": "Female" is present and "status":"married" [this should return id#2 from below data]

Table : cust_data

```
id(numeric) | connections (jsonb)
------------------------------

1, {"Persons": [
            {
              "personName": "Tom",
              "gender": "Male",
              "country": "USA",
              "status":"single"

            },
            {
            "personName": "Harry",
            "gender": "Male",
            "country": "USA",
            "status":"single"
            },
            {
            "personName": "Lisa",
            "gender": "Female",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "status":"single"
              }    
          ]
        }

        2,{
          "Persons": [
            {
              "personName": "Lisa",
              "gender": "Male",
              "country": "UK",
              "status":"single"
            },
            {
            "personName": "Harry",
            "gender": "Male",
            "country": "USA",
            "status":"single"
            },
            {
            "personName": "Lisa",
            "gender": "Female",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "status":"married"
              }    
          ]
        }

        3,{
          "Persons": [
            {
              "personName": "Lisa",
              "gender": "Male",
              "country": "UK",
              "status":"single"
            },
            {
            "personName": "Harry",
            "gender": "Male",
            "country": "USA",
            "status":"single"
            }   
          ]
        }
```

Comment: have you looked on official postgres page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Yes. But it pull all records. Here is the query -  SELECT id 
from cust_data t, jsonb_array_elements(t.connections->'persons') AS elem WHERE elem->>'gender' !='female' ;

Comment: please check persons. In your example it is capital letter. while in query it is written with small letter.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [boolean aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select id
from cust_data,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(connections->'Persons')
group by 1
having not bool_or(value->>'gender' = 'Female');

 id 
----
  3
(1 row)

select id
from cust_data,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(connections->'Persons')
group by 1
having bool_or(value->>'gender' = 'Female' and value->>'status' = 'married');

 id 
----
  2
(1 row)
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/JDGI58070)

---

If the arrays may be empty you should use `left join ... on true` instead of `lateral`. Add also `coalesce()` with appropriate default value for aggregates as they can yield `null`, e.g.:

```
select id
from cust_data
left join jsonb_array_elements(connections->'Persons') on true
group by 1
having not coalesce(bool_or(value->>'gender' = 'Female'), false);
```

Comment: Thanks! this query is not fetching ids where persons array is empty

Answer (score 0):

Query for 1:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(t.connections->'Persons') AS elem
    FROM cust_data  t
), findFemale AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test
   WHERE elem->>'gender' = 'Female'
) 
SELECT id FROM cust_data
WHERE id NOT IN  (select * from findFemale)
```

Query for 2:

```
 WITH test as (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(t.connections->'Persons') AS elem  
 from cust_data   t
 ) , findFemaleMarried as (
 select distinct id from test
 where 
 elem ->> 'gender' = 'Female' and elem ->> 'status' = 'married'
 )
 select * from findFemaleMarried
```

I hope above query will solve your problem.